# print CurrentUICulture using jQuery in UserControl

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

I have page written in ASP.NET using .NET 3.5 (Web Site Project).
I want to add some culture specific validators to my page using jQuery.

I wound nice tutorial about using Globalize plugin: http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.com/2012/09/globalize-and-jquery-validate.html

I'm **not** using MVC.

I want to print CurrentUICulture in my user control (ASCX) using console.log (just to check if I get correct value), but when I add one line to my control everything stops working:

```
console.log("<%System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name%>");
```

Some weird file are getting generated, for example `App_Web_ervntlyo.).cs` and they contain errors.

Other parts of my script are working well:

```
$("#<%=partYes.ClientID%>, #<%=partNo.ClientID%>").prop('checked', false);
```

How can I access CurrentUICulture in ASCX file? **Not in ASCX.CS**

Comment: You are missing an `=` sign in `"<%System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name%>"`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm so ashamed...I could swear that this line is correct, I looked at it for 20 minutes. Thanks for finding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET inline expressions require an `=` sign between the start of the directive `<%` and the expression.

You should write:

```
console.log("<%=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name %>");
```

Comment: This works as expected, thanks :) and sorry for silly typo question.